# Parsing XML using PHP 5.5

Tags: php, xml, xacml

I have a bit of code that takes in XML and attempts to validate it. However, I keep getting an error

> Error type: 8192
>
> Error message: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

From looking around it seems like there must be underlying code that uses assignment by reference e.g $foo = & ... I tried to change my code e.g. to use the technique used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094723/php-no-response-when-xml-validation-with-xsd) but to no avail.

```
$version = $_POST["xacmlversion"];
$source = $_POST["policy"];
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
    $source = stripslashes($source);
}
$xdoc = new DomDocument();
if ($version == 2){
   $xmlschema = 'xacml/xacml2.xsd';
} else {
   $xmlschema = 'xacml/xacml3.xsd';
   $version = 3;
}

$xdoc->LoadXML($source);
//Validate the XML file against the schema
$valid = $xdoc->schemaValidate($xmlschema);
```

So where's the blooper?

### UPDATE

Here is the root cause

```
Array
(
[type] => 8192
[message] => Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated
[file] => /home/www/wp-content/plugins/exec-php/includes/ajax.php
[line] => 64
)
```

Comment: Might be in the underlying DomDocument()-class?

Comment: Well that error message would also have a file name and line number, which would tell you exactly where the error is. It's nothing to do with this code. BTW `get_magic_quotes_gpc` has been obsolete for like 5 years, you can remove that whole clause.

Comment: @miken32 Yeah, I wrote that code 5 years ago :-) thanks for the update